# Override Jquery's function

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding

I have a huge application where `addClass` and `removeClass` of **jquery** is being used at numerous places in code. I want to perform some work on the element being class being altered of on the bases of what class is being added/removed. Longer route would be to add my piece of code everywhere in the application after `addClass` and `removeClass` but I was thinking if I can override these jquery's functions somehow then my life would be much easier. I have tried below code.

```
var oAddClass = jQuery.fn.addClass;
jQuery.fn.addClass = function (arg) {
    alert(this);
    alert(arg);

    // Now go back to jQuery's original size()
    return oAddClass.apply(this, arg);
};
```

But getting error "**Function.prototype.apply: argument is not an Object**" at `return oAddClass.apply(this, arg);`

Can someone help me out plzz.

Comment: I like questions like these, good attempt yourself. +1. Check this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-ask-ben-overriding-core-jquery-methods.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument for `.apply` must be an array-like object.

```
return oAddClass.apply(this, arguments);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to pass just the first argument from your wrapper function to `.apply()`, but the second parameter of `.apply()` should be an array. You can create an array from the `arguments` object:

```
  var args = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) args[i] = arguments[i];
  oAddClass.apply(this, args);
```

The `arguments` object is a special object initialized by the runtime in every function. It's a tricky thing to deal with and it can cause code optimization problems, but the simple use above is safe.

Comment: To convert the arguments object into an array, you can do aswell `var args = [].slice.call(arguments)`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon yes, you can, but passing the `arguments` object out of a function is very likely to cause the optimizer to completely give up on optimization. For some code that's not a problem of course.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against doing this for maintainability reasons: if another developer looks at the code and sees jQuery `.addClass`, it's very confusing if it does something other than remove the class.

I would just write a helper function with your own rules that calls `addClass` and/or `removeClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that [jQuery.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is documented to receive a single argument I believe that [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) should be used instead of [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Food for though: jQuery does not document its internal self use patterns so you never know when the replaced `addClass` method will be called (example with toggle class below).

```js
(function () {
  var oAddClass = jQuery.fn.addClass;
  jQuery.fn.addClass = function(arg) {
    return oAddClass.call(this, arg);
  };
}());

$('#foo').addClass('foo bar');

$('span').addClass(function(index) {
  if (index == 0) {
    return 'bar';
  }
  return 'foo';
});

$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('#foo').toggleClass('foo');
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: green;
}
.bar {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">Hello World</div>
<span>Span 1</span>
<br />
<span>Span 2</span>
<br />
<button>Toggle .foo on the div</button>
```